# ld.exe crashing in MinGW

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, linker, mingw

I recently got a new laptop which runs Windows 8 (I want to dual boot with Ubuntu but haven't gotten around to it yet). I've been working on porting my projects to Windows and getting them to work on here. I'm using MinGW and GCC through the CodeBlocks IDE.

I've succeeded in building all of my libraries into .a files, including Boost (the few parts that need to be built), SFML, and wxWidgets, which I'm compiling as debug static libraries. When I try to build my project, however, I get to the linking stage and then I get the standard Windows "ld.exe has stopped responding" dialog. When I close that, the linker finishes and I get the following output in the CB build log:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: BFD (GNU Binutils) 2.23.2 assertion fail ../../binutils-2.23.2/bfd/cofflink.c:2389
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 5 exit status
```

I've found several threads on this in the wxWidgets forums, where ld.exe crashes when people are building wxWidgets. The fix everyone claims is to build wxWidgets with -fno-keep-inline-dllexport being passed in the C++ flags. I've rebuilt wxWidgets with that flag, and also rebuilt my entire program in CodeBlocks with the same flag. Still the same output.

It's also worth noting that my program takes about a full minute to compile each object file, and about 4 minutes to run the linker, which is significantly slower than my old laptop. My new laptop has 6GB of RAM and a 2.0GHz 4-core AMD CPU, where my old one, while it was Ubuntu, had only 1GB of RAM and a 1.0GHz 1-core Intel CPU.

Any advice would be helpful. If you need more information, I'd be willing to supply it.

Comment: Looks like it's the assert here that fails:
https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=bfd/cofflink.c;h=75ef7aff29245a3371050736bbd5aabfa87be52a;hb=HEAD#l2387
As far as I can see, this line hasn't been changed for at least a couple of years. Are you sure you don't have a broken library or something?

Comment: Not as far as I can tell. It's a relatively fresh MinGW install, and like I said, I was able to build Boost, SFML, and wxWidgets properly without ld crashing (and I've even built them since I first started having the trouble with my project).

Comment: So, can you cut down your app to give a direct part of it that causes the problem? Alternatively, you could try passing --strip-all to `ld` - the section that goes wrong is trying to check that the size is correct for the output of debug symbols, so if you remove those it shouldn't got wrong (there at least!)

Comment: I'm not even sure where I'd start on trying to find that. I guess I can try creating a new project with the same dependencies? And I'll test it with --strip-all, but this is a debug build, so it's not a permanent solution.

Comment: I created a new project with the same dependencies, the same linked libraries, and the same header imports in the code, and built it with the exact same compiler and linker options, but it did not result in the crash. Of course, the executable was much smaller. I wonder if that could be it.

I also got rid of the -g options and passed --strip-all to test it, and it didn't crash. Like I said, though, that's not a permanent solution.

Comment: Well, as all I know about this particular assert is what I've gathered from looking at the source code, I can't really say what it is trigggered by. Your next step would be to slowly introduce more and more of your original code, and try to determine if there is something in particular that triggers this.

Comment: I just attempted to compile it again, the previous compilation was false. It said --strip-all was an invalid argument, after some research I decided -s was what you likely meant. ld still crashed with the same dialog, but the console output was different. Now it's just

`collect2.exe: error: ld returned 255 exit status`

Comment: I'm wondering if it isn't to do with the executable size. The executable was generated this time, although it doesn't work, but even without symbols it's 16MB. With the symbols it's closer to 130MB.

Comment: It may be something to do with size, but I'm guessing that producing 100+ MB of symbols may also contain the odd symbol that is "strange" in some way. I regularly build executable files at work that are 100+MB, but not sure how much of that is symbols really (haven't looked at that).

Comment: Of course, I'm normally building for Linux, which uses a different type of symbols in a different type of output file. This type is only used for Windows. However, I still think there is probably something in one of your files that causes a problem. Without a system to reproduce this, it's pretty hard to debug/understand what goes on. If you download the sources, you could perhaps add a printout next to the assert and see what it actually has as inputs? [The function is far from trivial, last time I read about "good programming style", writing functions that are ~1000 lines long wasn't there.]

Comment: I don't know how to explain it or what changed, but I just attempted a build once more, with generating debug symbols, basically as it was when I first built it, and it worked properly. It took a proper amount of time to build, didn't have any errors, and built a working executable. I wish I could say what fixed the problem, but that's the best answer I can give. It just...solved itself...